# The selected system font, Inter, does not have crossbars on the capital I. This is a bad choice

Tags: system

I guess this is the discussion forum, so I'm raising the issue here. I saw an article stating that Inter has been selected as the system font, but its capital "i" looks like a lower-case L. A font without crossbars on the capital "i" is pretty much a bad choice for anything, but certainly a system font.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry to say it, but this is not a discussion forum. You'd have better success debating this on https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/new/ or even post an issue at https://github.com/elementary/default-settings.

Comment: OK, thanks! I checked the elementary site but it doesn't have any links to a forum or other discussion venue.

Comment: As mentioned, this is not that. This is a very specific, and I do mean very specific, question and answer format site. Discussion threads are definitely off-topic here.

Comment: Yes, and? I don’t see anyone challenging your statement.